# Confidence interval for multiple regression parameter

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, multiple-regression

I'm given the least squares model:

```
Y = B0 + B1x1 + B2x2 + B3x1x2
Y = 12 -2x1 + 7x2 +5x1x2

n = 20
```

as well as some RSS's

```
> sum( lm( y ~ 1 )$residuals^2 )                                  #$ (to fix display bug)
[1] 456 
> sum( lm( y ~ x1 )$residuals^2 )                                 #$
[1] 320 
> sum( lm( y ~ x2 )$residuals^2 )                                 #$
[1] 360 
> sum( lm( y ~ x1 + x2 )$residuals^2 )                            #$
[1] 288 
> sum( lm( y ~ x1 + x2 + I(x1*x2) )$residuals^2 )                 #$
[1] 240
```

So, I know the least squares estimate for `B3` is 5.

I did ANOVA on the full model versus the model where `B3 = 0`. I found the F statistic for `B3 = 0` to be 3.2.

Now I need to find a 95% confidence interval for B3. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: The F-statistics you found there should be useful. Try to calculate the p-value of this ANOVA test. The resultant p-value should also be the p-value of the interaction term in your model 5. Now, you have the p-value and the point estimate, and you know that regression coefficients are tested with t-statistics, and you also know the df is 1... you should be able to deduct what the standard error of the interaction term is.

Comment: why not look at the output of `summary(lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + I(x1*x2)))` for the standard error? Also, the `I()` is unnecessary.

Comment: @ndoogan +1, but the `*` operator in R formulas includes the main effects, while `:` represents the interaction-only. That is the formula `y ~ x1*x2` is equivalent to `y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2`

Comment: `?confint` will generate one from the model (though it's easy by hand from the output, as ndoogan suggests).

Comment: @Glen_b you are exactly right. However, if the main effects are already present in the formula, the x1*x2 notation will not re-add them.